# Repeated AJAX requests slow browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssi

There is a small web page that requests an XML file from a web server. The web server updates this file twice a second with new data to be displayed on the web page.

After the page is left running for a while, it will slow down the entire browser whenever it gets the new data from the server (twice a second). The problem is intermittent - sometimes it lasts a few seconds, sometimes it lasts longer.

The problem exists in Firefox.

```
function getData() {
  var dataVal = parseFloat($("#data").html().substring(0, 100));
  doSomethingWithVal(XTEval); // seemingly irrelevant, as it lags without this function too
}

t = 0.5;

function process_xml() {
  var xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

  if (xmlhttp === null) {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
    return;
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      getData();
      setTimeout('process_xml()', t * 1000);  // moved from end of function to here based on a suggestion
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.shtml", true);
  xmlhttp.send("");
}

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (window.ActiveXObject)
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  return null;
}
```

data.shtml simply contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<!--#echo var="someVal.val" -->
```

Perhaps there is a different/better approach than using AJAX?

Comment: It would be a very good idea to declare your "xmlhttp" variable with `var` in that function. Without that, it's a global variable, and successive calls to "process_xml" with overwrite its previous value.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that, and I've made that change. I inherited this code and have been slowly updating it.

Comment: Am I right that getData is not in your code and getXTE is not called from process_xml? Can you either confirm this or fix your example (which might include fixing XTEVal and dataVal)

Comment: @rene Thanks for catching that. In my actual code, getXTE is called instead of getData. I was simplifying the code for SO and forgot to change the getXTE function to getData.

Comment: Session locks with simultaneous ajax calls in php is a known issue, not sure if it would be same with SSI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is the problem, but if the round-trip to the server, plus parsing and everything else you're doing in `process_xml` takes more than 500ms, then you'll wind up with several requests in-flight at the same time, which will eventually clog the pipes (browsers have a limit to how many the can handle concurrently).  You're better off calling your `setTimeout` in the `onreadystatechanged` handler, after all the work in there is complete.

Comment: I've made the change, but no cigar. It still slows down after running for a minute or so.

Comment: Is the problem only in FireFox or in all browsers?

Comment: It looks like Chrome is not affected. It's hard to know for sure though because the problem is sporadic.